# iphone as a mouse

Tags: iphone, mouse

What tools you suggest to use to create iphone mouse app.

I wan't to create client (iphone) and server(mac) apps.

Problem is with server. I don't know what should I use to take control over the mouse.

I/O Kit?

Plese post any suggestions.